# Mono garbage collection on a Linux VPS

Tags: c#, mono

I've been trying to get the server for my C# game to run on Linux, and it works well except for one problem: The garbage collector doesn't seem to give any memory back to the OS, so it eventually reaches the limit and crashes.

I noticed that using System.GC.Collect after operations that free a lot of memory (changing maps, or players leaving) prevents the OutOfMemoryError, but it still uses all but about 30MB of the available memory (1GB) which still makes it likely to crash when trying to allocate smaller amounts of memory.

I don't think it's a memory leak, since on Windows it uses a maximum of 60MB when there is one player online, but having one person connect and disconnect repeatedly is enough to use up all of the memory on the Linux server.

**mono --version:**

```
Mono JIT compiler version 2.10.8 (tarball Mon Feb 25 19:25:00 MSK 2013)
Copyright (C) 2002-2011 Novell, Inc, Xamarin, Inc and Contributors. www.mono-project.com
        TLS:           __thread
        SIGSEGV:       altstack
        Notifications: epoll
        Architecture:  x86
        Disabled:      none
        Misc:          softdebug
        LLVM:          supported, not enabled.
        GC:            Included Boehm (with typed GC and Parallel Mark)
```

The OS is CentOS, and the VPS platform is OpenVZ.

Comment: You should share your Mono version information (mono --version)

Comment: I added it to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably a matter of garbage collector issue. Try starting your game with `mono --gc=sgen` parameter. I know it works in some cases.

Comment: Thanks! Apparently my version has a bug with sgen but that was easily fixed by making the changes here: http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.comp.gnome.mono.patches/184020